# Python 2.7.9 install requests on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I keep trying to install requests, but every time I do it starts, then gives me this error. Is there any way I can get around this or fix this error so that I can use requests?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1265, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.extras):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2291, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2484, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2508, in _compute_dependencies
    parsed = next(parse_requirements(distvers))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 45, in <lambda>
    next = lambda o: o.next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2573, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'charset-normalizer ~=2.0.0', 'at', ' ~=2.0.0')

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\l--l\pip\pip.log
```

I have gotten into the files correctly but I cannot seem to get it to download requests.

Comment: `requests`, like most other Python libraries nowadays, doesn't support Python 2. Why are you using it, anyway? It reached its end of support life over 2 years ago, and was deprecated for *many* years before then.

Answer (score 0):

## Re-Install pip

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
python2.7 get-pip.py
```

## Install requests

```
python2.7 -m pip install requests
```

OR Manual install

```
git clone git://github.com/psf/requests.git
cd requests
python2.7 -m pip install .
```

Comment: You don't need to put it anywhere. you can even delete it after installing with pip

Comment: installing it with pip doesnt seem to work. the command python2.7 -m pip install wont work